# Select randômico mysql com Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho este código que seleciona randomicamente, os usuários na minha DB:

```
def select_random(request):
    try:
      last = User.objects.count() - 1

      index_one = random.randint(0, last)
      index_two = random.randint(0, last - 1)

      if index_two == index_one:
        index_two = last

      object_user = User.objects.all()[index_one]

      return object_user
    except:
      return False
```

O problema:
Se houver bastante usuários para selecionar, isso pode dar problema né?

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso, usando o próprio *django*?

Ou existe outra maneira de fazer isso independente se for usar as funções do *Django*? No caso, **gambiarra mesmo**?

Comment: A galera nãos sabe responder, negativa a pergunta e nem comentar comenta. Brincadeira isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você deseja retornar um usuário aleatório, então segue:

```
User.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
```

O .first() equivale ao [0].

Você pode ler mais sobre ordenação [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo, porém, isso não é correto, pelo menos eu pesquisei sobre, e maioria dos lugares dizem que ao usar isso em um servidor com muitos dados pode dar ruim!